# backdrop-filter leaves artefacts in rounded corners

Tags: css, safari, css-transitions, css-animations

I have an element with a fade CSS animation and child elements that have a backdrop-filter applied to blur the background in Safari.

There are two issues:

1. The element has rounded borders. Dark shadows can be seen in each corner.
2. When the element is faded in, the blur is not drawn until the fade animation is completed.

DEMO on Safari and iOS Safari:

https://appifiny.co.uk/demo/

Removing the backdrop-filter removes the artefacts from the corners.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue - as I don't have access to iOS (etc.) but some border-radius issues can be solved by adding

```
#YourElement{
  perspective:1px;
}
```

to the element that has the rounded corners.

Try it out and please leave us an update.

Comment: This workaround doesn't work in Safari 9.1.2. And Apple fixed the bug in Safari 10.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a Safari bug and is fixed in Technology Preview 6:

[Safari TP 6](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/)

I'm still not sure about issue #2 though.